# Secure Solr search engine on Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, solr, azure-vm-role

I have installed a **Solr** instance on **Azure VM** and I have also configured Solr on `port:8983` so that I can access it everywhere for my MVC website. e.g: `_mysolr.azurewebsites.net:8983_`

My MVC website are setup on Azure. I want to restrict Solr so that no one else can access except my MVC website in Azure.

How I can put security on Solr or Azure VM so that no one can access it except my own website for getting search result.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if what you are looking for is similar to what i hav done.
Assuming you have made changes to

```
   jetty.xml,webdefault.xml and created realm.properties for username and password
```

I have set up solr with cake php and for security i added username and password.This only allows my website to access solr.

```
 What my code looks like in php
 Change the SOLRHOST  value to
 define("SOLRHOST", "username:password@localhost");

  make changes in delta import command
 * * * * * wget --quiet -O /dev/null       
 'http://username:password@localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import'
```

So now only those pages or website can access your solr who have username and password.
Let me know if this is what you were looking for